# TFS 2010 and .htaccess file in source control

Tags: .htaccess

we use Team foundation server 2010 for our web projects.

Sometimes we use PHP and .htaccess files. Is there a way to upload any file which name starts with dot (.htaccess, .test etc.) to TFS ?

any server configuration changes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's supported out of the box.
Simply go to Source Control Explorer and select the "Add items to folder" icon.  Add the .htaccess file (or whatever else you like) and check in your pending changes.

Comment: The problem is when adding files to source control from network share (\\server) it can not find file. :/

Otherwise works.

Comment: Also problem is when source control folder is mapped to network share, it can not copy file to this destionation when adding from local disk.

Comment: I have the same issue. Mapped network share and TFS doesn't think I have the dot files on my local disk, while Windows Explorer sees them just fine.